# jQuery - Clicking link fails because the containing element disappears beforehand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus, blur

I'm writing a simple suggestions box for an input field. When I click into the field, a hidden element appears underneath the box, containing some links matching the field's content.

The suggestion box is programmed to disappear when the input field loses focus.

However, when I try to click any link from the suggestion box, the input field loses focus first, causing the suggestion box containing all the links to disappear, and the click event "misses its target".

I've tried to demonstrate this behavior here: https://jsfiddle.net/fugasjunior/cxh8bmp9/1/

```html
<input placeholder="some text here">
<div class="hideme" style="display:none">
  <a href="google.com" target="_blank">Link to some site</a>
</div>
```

```js
$("input").focus(function () {
  $(".hideme").css("display", "block");
});

$("input").blur(function () {
  $(".hideme").css("display", "none");
});
```

My temporary solution was to set a small timeout before hiding the element. However, I think that's far too unreliable and overall not an ideal solution. Is there any better solution to this problem? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to catch the click event of the links inside the `<div>` and change the `display` to `none`. For example:

```
$( "input" ).focus( function () {
    $( ".hideme" ).css( "display", "block" );
} );

$( ".hideme a" ).click( function () {
    $( ".hideme" ).css( "display", "none" );
} );
```

Basically, any time a link inside the `div` is clicked (i.e. `.hideme a`), the `<div>` is hidden.

However, this may not be the desired solution, because it would then be required to identify all the events associated with hiding the `<div>` (i.e. clicking elsewhere on the page would not hide the `<div>` by default). Alternatively, the `<input>` element could be changed to capture a `.click` which toggles the display on and off so that the user can also re-hide the `<div>` by clicking on the `<input>` element again.

Apologies that this may not answer the original question completely.